# Create a new array with difference of array elements in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have this object with 2 arrays inside, How can I create a new array with difference of every element in array1 to corresponding element in array2.
For example here resulting array should be

```
["$1", "$5", "$6"]
```

```js
{
  "2": ["$3","$4","$8"], 
  "3": ["$4","$9","$2"]
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt? Remember that SO is here to help you debug code, not to write it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

1. First, you need to get elements at the same index from both the array
2. Convert them to `Number` type
3. Get the difference but be sure to use `Math.abs` to get the absolute value.
4. Return the result by adding the `$` before it.

```js
const obj = {
  "2": ["$3", "$4", "$8"],
  "3": ["$4", "$9", "$2"],
};

const result = obj["2"].map((el, i) => {
  // First Step
  const first = obj["2"][i];
  const second = obj["3"][i];

  // Second Step
  const regex = /\d+/;
  const firstNumber = parseInt(first.match(regex));
  const secondNumber = parseInt(second.match(regex));
  
  // Third Step
  const diff = Math.abs(firstNumber - secondNumber);
  
  // Fourth step
  return `$${diff}`;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const object = {
  "2": ["$3","$4","$8"], 
  "3": ["$4","$9","$2"]
}
 
const keys = Object.keys(object)
 
const keysReversed = keys.reverse()
 
const differenceArray = []

const length = object[keysReversed[0]].length

for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    const element1 = object[keysReversed[0]][index].replace('$', '');
    const element2 = object[keysReversed[1]][index].replace('$', '');
    differenceArray.push(`$${Math.abs(element1 - element2)}`)
}

console.log(differenceArray) // [ '$1', '$5', '$6' ]
```